# Mysql executes two if statements although one is true the other is false

Tags: mysql

I have this stored procedure

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER le_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON inbox
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
declare last_inserted_number VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '0800100200';
declare last_inserted_message VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'Lorem Ipsum';

set last_inserted_number = NEW.in_number;
set last_inserted_message = NEW.in_message;

if(select exists(select id from transactions where tel =last_inserted_number) = 0) then

insert into transactions (message,tel)values(last_inserted_message,last_inserted_number);

if(select exists(select id from transactions where tel =last_inserted_number) > 0) then

insert into outbox (out_message,out_number) values("there was an error",last_inserted_number);

end if;end if;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

This is how it is supposed to work.If i insert something into the inbox table,the trigger picks the message and telephone number and inserts it into transactions table if that number is not already in transactions.If the trigger finds that that number exists in transactions,it inserts into outbox that there was an error.

In my code,the stored procedure inserts into the error table every time i insert into inbox.What's wrong with my procedure?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logical fallacy.  After you execute the `insert`, the value exists in the table.  That causes the second condition to find the row.  I think you want an `else` statement:

```
if (not exists(select id from transactions where tel = last_inserted_number)) then
    insert into transactions(message, tel)
        values(last_inserted_message, last_inserted_number);
else
    insert into outbox(out_message, out_number)
        values("there was an error", last_inserted_number);
end if;
```

Note that I changed the logic by removing `= 0` and using `not exists`.  Also, it is good practice to prepend all variables with something like `v_` so they are not confused with columns in tables.

Comment: I have so many conditions that must be met so i was particularly avoiding else.Can the use of case be an alternative?

Comment: @user3286430 . . . `case` is a SQL statement.  You need control flow in the trigger, so use `if` along with `else`.  I fail to see how repeating a condition in any way is simpler or better than just using `else`.